# group registry for npm doesn't has effect with order set

Tags: npm, nexus

**Question**
I setup nexus server for my npm registry with both private and proxy registries. The config is:

> 1. proxy: npmjs-org, remote repository: https://registry.npmjs.org
> 2. hosted: npm-hosted, manul upload module **antd 3.20.0** to this private registry
> 3. group: npm-public, members: npmjs-org and npm-hosted

According to nexus offical docs,

> Note that the order of the repositories listed in the Member section is > important. When the repository manage searches for a component in a 
>   repository group, it will return the first match. To reorder a 
>   repository in this list, click and the drag the repositories and groups > in the Members list or use the arrow buttons between the Available and 
>   Members list. These arrows can be used to add and remove repositories as > well.
>   https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/configuration/repository-management#RepositoryManagement-ManagingRepositoriesandRepositoryGroups

I expected to install **antd 3.20.0** with config:

> 1. **npm-public** contains **npm-hosted** and **npmjs-org**
> 2. **npm-hosted** is above **npmjs-org**
>      [image]

but I got **antd 3.20.1**. 
Is this nexus's problem or I miss something in the config ?

**PS**
I also try bellow

I got antd 3.20.1

> 1. **npm-public** contains **npm-hosted** and **npmjs-org**
> 2. **npmjs-org** is above **npm-hosted**

I got antd 3.20.0

> **npm-public** containers **npm-hosted**

**Environment**

> 1. nexus 3.14 or 3.17
> 2. node 10.15.0
> 3. module antd in npm-hosted: 3.20.0, antd in npmjs-org: 3.20.1
> 4. the command used for download module is  npm install antd --save  --verbose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a bit of a misunderstanding here.  The order of repositories in a group is only going to matter if there is the exact same version of a component in more than one repository.  So if you had two repositories that contained antd@3.20.0 the component would be downloaded from the one that is higher in the group.

If you need version 3.20.0, you should download it using 'npm install antd#3.20.0'.